# Fancybox pop-up, trouble finding error in code

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, vimeo

trying to get a pop-up lightbox for my vimeo video. I've tried about 6 different kinds and can't seem to get them to work. Can anyone see a problem in the code with the lightbox. I am getting linked to the actual vimeo page instead of it just popping up on the same page

This is the code for the fancybox and the rest is the full code:

```
<div id="video"><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="https://vimeo.com/63197306"><img src="Images/video_pic.png" name="video_pic" width="638" height="391" id="video_pic"></a></div>  



<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Motivational Productions</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script tpe="text/javascript" src= src="FancyBox/lib/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="FancyBox/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head><body>
<div id="content_wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo_drop"><img src="Images/opaque_image-01-01.png" width="195" height="150"></div>
        <div id="logo"><img src="Images/main_logo-01-01.png" width="434" height="140"></div>
<div id="social">
            <div id="twitter_icon"><img src="Images/twitter_icon.png" width="25" height="25"></div>
            <div id="facebook_icon"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/motivationalpro"><img src="Images/facebook_icon.png" width="25" height="25"></a></div>
            <div id="vimeo_icon"><a href="https://vimeo.com/user2662413"><img src="Images/vimeo_icon.png" width="25" height="25"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div id="learn">Learn More About Us»</div>
        <div id="get_in_touch">Get In Touch»</div>
    </div>
  <div id="space"></div>
<div id="content">
        <div id="slider">
            <div id="right_pic"><img src="Images/right_pic.png" width="609" height="342"></div>
          <div id="video"><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="https://vimeo.com/63197306"><img src="Images/video_pic.png" name="video_pic" width="638" height="391" id="video_pic"></a></div>
          <div id="left_pic"><img src="Images/left_pic.png" width="760" height="439"></div>
</div>
    </div>
<div id="footer">
<div id="footer_wrap">
        <div id="footer_header"><div id="footer_img"><img src="Images/footer_header-01.png" name="footers_img" width="948" height="54" id="footers_img"></div></div>
        <div id="footer_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </div>
        <div id="footer_get_in_touch">Get In Touch»</div>
        <div id="footer_learn_about">Learn More About Us»</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div id="space"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the code above is exactly what you have, then you are missing to load the fancybox js file. Also you have an extra `src` in this line `<script tpe="text/javascript" src= src="FancyBox/lib/jquery-1.9.0.min.js">` AND a typo : `tpe` should be `type`. If you have a HTML5 DOCTYPE, you could remove that attribute though. The best way to detect those errors is validating your code and use a browser (Firefox) add-on to detect what scripts and css stylesheets were successfully loaded, otherwise check your paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an additional class `fancybox.iframe` to your `fancybox` element. Also, you need to update your Vimeo link to `http://player.vimeo.com/video/63197306?autoplay=1`

Change this block

```
<div id="video">
  <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="https://vimeo.com/63197306">
    <img src="Images/video_pic.png" name="video_pic" width="638" height="391" id="video_pic">
  </a>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="video">
  <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" rel="group" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/63197306?autoplay=1">
    <img src="Images/video_pic.png" name="video_pic" width="638" height="391" id="video_pic">
  </a>
</div>
```